# Disable custom module Block Caching or force correct caching

Tags: blocks, navigation, caching

I have build a custom module that builds out a list of child page links based on 'this' page's id.

Logged in it works as expected. But an anon user has problems which range from the block not showing at all, to the most recent problem [in D10] of links from another NID listing instead. Anon users problems are resolved on a cache clear.

Initially the blocks had all sorts of caching tags to pick up page edits / navigation changes an so on, but as the anon user problems persisted, these were removed. I have also uninstalled "Internal Page Cache" but "Internal Dynamic Page Cache" is still installed.

This has been a problem since the initial build in Drupal 8. Initially I had this, which worked as it should for logged in users, but not anon users

```
'#cache' => [
  'tags' => [
    'node_list',
    'config:system.menu.main',
    'config:system.menu.footer',
   ],
   'contexts' => [
     'url.path',
    ], 
  ],
],
```

Eventually to fix the anon users problem, I modified to this

```
'#cache' => [
  'disabled' => TRUE
],
```

I have added: public function getCacheMaxAge(){..} in an attempt to prevent the anon user cache, but it did not work.

The two blocks are as follows:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\child_menu_units\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

/**
 * Provides a Parent Menu item Block
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "child_menu_units_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Child Menu Units block"),
 * )
 */
class ChildMenuUnitBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $output = [];
    $child_units = [];

    // Find the menu item corresponding to the entity (node).
    $menu_link_service = \Drupal::getContainer()
      ->get('plugin.manager.menu.link');

    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
      $nid = $node->id();
      $route_params = ['node' => $nid];
      $menu_links = $menu_link_service->loadLinksByRoute('entity.node.canonical', $route_params);
      if (!empty($menu_links)) {
        // We found a menu link so we can continue with generating the tree.
        // First, setup the parameters: we need one level starting with the menu
        // link we found, but excluding it from the tree.
        $root_menu_item = reset($menu_links);
        $menu_parameters = new \Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuTreeParameters();
        $menu_parameters->setMaxDepth(1);
        $menu_parameters->setRoot($root_menu_item->getPluginId());
        $menu_parameters->excludeRoot();
        // Get the tree.
        $menu_name = $root_menu_item->getMenuName();
        $menu_tree_service = \Drupal::service('menu.link_tree');
        $tree = $menu_tree_service->load($menu_name, $menu_parameters);
        // Apply some manipulators (checking the access, sorting).
        $manipulators = [
          ['callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:checkNodeAccess'],
          ['callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:checkAccess'],
          ['callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:generateIndexAndSort'],
        ];
        $tree = $menu_tree_service->transform($tree, $manipulators);

        foreach ($tree as $item) {
          // Only show accessible and enabled links.
          if ((!$item->access->isAllowed()) or (!$item->link->isEnabled())) {
            continue;
          }
          // get the truncated summmary text for each item
          //$summary = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadByProperties(array('path' => $item->link->getUrlObject()->toString()));
          $url_obj = $item->link->getUrlObject();
          $node = self::nodeFromPath($url_obj->toString());

          $summary = '';
          if (isset($node)) {
            $viewBuilder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node');
            $value = $node->get('body');
            $summary_array = $viewBuilder->viewField($value, 'teaser');
            $summary = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($summary_array);
            $summary = strip_tags($summary);
            $summary = \Drupal\Component\Utility\Unicode::truncate($summary, 90, TRUE);
          }
          $title = $item->link->getTitle();
          //$title = \Drupal\Component\Utility\Unicode::truncate($title, 50, true);
          $child_units[] = [
            'title' => $title,
            'url_obj' => $url_obj,
            'summary' => $summary,
          ];
        }
        //     And the last step is to actually build the tree.
        //      $output['my_custom_menu'] = $menu_tree_service->build($tree);

        $output = [
          '#theme' => 'child_menu_units',
          '#child_units' => $child_units,
          '#cache' => [
            'disabled' => TRUE
          ],

        ];
      }
      return $output;
    }
  }

  function nodeFromPath($path) {
    $path = \Drupal::service('path_alias.manager')
      ->getPathByAlias($path);
    preg_match('/node\/(\d+)/', $path, $matches);
    $nid = $matches[1];
    return Node::load($nid);
  }

  /**
   * Try and stop the block from caching.
   *
   * @return int
   *   The maximum time in seconds that this object may be cached.
   */
  public function getCacheMaxAge() {
    return 0;
  }

}
```

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\child_menu_units\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;

/**
 * Provides a Parent Menu item Block
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "child_lvl2_menu_listing_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Child Menu Lvl 2 Listing block"),
 * )
 */
class ChildLvl2MenuListingBlock extends BlockBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $output = [];
    $child_units = [];

    // Find the menu item corresponding to the entity (node).
    $menu_link_service = \Drupal::getContainer()
      ->get('plugin.manager.menu.link');

    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
      $nid = $node->id();
      $route_params = ['node' => $nid];
      $menu_links = $menu_link_service->loadLinksByRoute('entity.node.canonical', $route_params);
      if (!empty($menu_links)) {
        // We found a menu link so we can continue with generating the tree.
        // First, setup the parameters: we need one level starting with the menu
        // link we found, but excluding it from the tree.
        $root_menu_item = reset($menu_links);
        $menu_parameters = new \Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuTreeParameters();
        $menu_parameters->setMaxDepth(1);
        $menu_parameters->setRoot($root_menu_item->getPluginId());
        $menu_parameters->excludeRoot();
        // Get the tree.
        $menu_name = $root_menu_item->getMenuName();
        $menu_tree_service = \Drupal::service('menu.link_tree');
        $tree = $menu_tree_service->load($menu_name, $menu_parameters);
        // Apply some manipulators (checking the access, sorting).
        $manipulators = [
          ['callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:checkNodeAccess'],
          ['callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:checkAccess'],
          ['callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:generateIndexAndSort'],
        ];
        $tree = $menu_tree_service->transform($tree, $manipulators);

        foreach ($tree as $item) {
          // Only show accessible and enabled links.
          if ((!$item->access->isAllowed()) or (!$item->link->isEnabled())) {
            continue;
          }
          $url_obj = $item->link->getUrlObject();

          $node = self::nodeFromPath($url_obj->toString());

          $type = '';
          if (isset($node)) {
            $viewBuilder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node');
            $type_id = $node->get('field_type')->entity;
            if (isset($type_id->tid->value)){
              $term = Term::load($type_id->tid->value);
              $type = $term->getName();
            }

          }


          $title = $item->link->getTitle();
          //$title = \Drupal\Component\Utility\Unicode::truncate($title, 50, TRUE);
          $child_units[] = [
            'title' => $title,
            'url_obj' => $url_obj,
            'type' => $type,
          ];
        }
        //     And the last step is to actually build the tree.
        //      $output['my_custom_menu'] = $menu_tree_service->build($tree);

        $output = [
          '#theme' => 'child_lvl2_menu_listing',
          '#child_units' => $child_units,
          '#cache' => [
            'disabled' => TRUE
          ],

        ];
      }
      return $output;
    }
  }

  function nodeFromPath($path) {
    $path = \Drupal::service('path_alias.manager')
      ->getPathByAlias($path);
    preg_match('/node\/(\d+)/', $path, $matches);
    $nid = $matches[1];
    return Node::load($nid);
  }

}
```

EDIT:

In the THEME.theme file I have:

```
function THEME_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  if($vars['derivative_plugin_id'] == 'childmenuunitsblock' || $vars['derivative_plugin_id'] == 'childmenulvl2listingblock') {
    $vars['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
  }
}
```

I also tried changing this to

```
function THEME_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  if($vars['plugin_id'] == 'childmenuunitsblock' || $vars['plugin_id'] == 'childmenulvl2listingblock') {
    $vars['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
  }
}
```

I also noticed that ChildLvl2MenuListingBlock does not have

```
 public function getCacheMaxAge() {
    return 0;
  }
```

found in the ChildMenuUnitBlock. When this is added the ChildLvl2MenuListingBlock fails to show at all for any users.

I also just tried splitting the two blocks into the individual modules but the same problems found with the single module setup were then still present in the separated version

EDIT 2:
/admin/structure/block
ChildMenuUnitBlock is on one region and ChildLvl2MenuListingBlock in another. As the ChildMenuUnitBlock seems reliable, I tried removing the ChildLvl2MenuListingBlock and adding ChildMenuUnitBlock in instead - but this block then failed to show or started displaying the same problems as ChildLvl2MenuListingBlock

Is having two blocks from the same custom module the source of this caching problem?

Is there an alternative method of getting a parent's child pages along with the child page's taxonomy term?

Comment: I think all that's missing is the current node in the cache tags. `'node:' . $node->id()`.

Comment: Adding a cache context on `user.roles:anonymous` may solve your issue as well, if the anonymous user is not working correctly..

Comment: max-age is not fully implemented in Core: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2352009